# Why do I get a NPE after assigning an Integer variable with value null to an int variable?

Tags: java

I want to know how the compiler reads this code.

```
public class obj {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer obj = null; //line4
        int x = obj;   //line 5
        System.out.println(x); //line6  
    }
}
```

My understanding is that line 5 can do auto unboxing which means it converts the `Integer` type to primitive `int`.

But I am not calling any method on `x`, just printing. Why is it giving me a `NullPointerException`?.

Comment: Read up on autoboxing and unboxing. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html

Comment: `null` cannot be assigned to a variable of type `int`

Answer (score 3):

Autoboxing here means that

```
int x = obj;
```

is actually:

```
int x = obj.intValue();
```

and hence the NullPointerException, as obj is null.

Answer (score 0):

Java has something called *autoboxing* where the Integer object is automatically converted to an int primative.

Comment: so its just converting object to primitive,then why we are getting exception if we are not calling any method on it

Answer (score 0):

Look at the bytecode

```
javap -c com.interviews.practise.obj
```